# Difference between jquery extend and simple copying a variable

Tags: jquery

I understand advantages of using jquery extend but are following two cases exactly similar or is one better than other and why?

```
obj1 = $.extend(true, {}, elements);
```

..

```
obj1 = elements;
```

**Update:**
Answer Explanation:
Following should clear the confusion

```
​obj = {"value":4};
obj_test = obj;
obj.value = 5
alert(obj_test.value);
```

​

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second case you don't "copy" the object, but create a second reference to it.

So in the first case it's a copy - 2 objects stored in 2 variables.

In the second - the single object referred by 2 variables (not a copy).

Comment: Interesting. I did not know that.

Answer (score 0):

First method is used to `deep copy an Object` .

```
var elements = {
   name : 'John',
   age : 23
}

var obj1 = $.extend(true, {}, elements);
obj1.name = 'Bill';

console.log('Original : '+ elements.name);
console.log('Deep Copy : ' + obj1.name);
```

Second is just `copying over the reference` of the object.

```
var obj2 = elements;
console.log('Original : '+ elements.name);
console.log('Reference Copy : ' + obj2.name);
```

**[check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/Bw4dj/)**

In the first case both objects point to different memory locations . So changing the property will only affect the objects that were changed.

In the second case both point to the same memory location. So effect on 1 will have an intermittent  effect on another..